# Manipulating Application Bars in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML from Code Behind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, commandbar

This might be a trivial beginner question and I have found quite a bit of related information for Windows and Silverlight apps but nothing that would directly help me. I'm writing a Windows **Phone** 8.1/WinRT app in C# and XAML, and I would like to programmatically modify application bars created in XAML. For instance, there is a button I want to include in debug builds only, using preprocessor directives in code behind.

In the following XAML code I'm creating a BottomAppBar with two buttons. How can I create the second button (AppBarAddSampleItemsButton) including all properties in code behind?

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar >
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarNewItemButton"
                          Label="New item"
                          Icon="Add" Command="{Binding GoToAddItemPageCommand}" />
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarAddSampleItemsButton"
                          Label="Add sample items"
                          Command="{Binding GoToAddSampleItemssPageCommand}" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</prism:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample code creating an [AppBarButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) in the code behind and adding it to [BottomAppBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.bottomappbar) of the current *Page*:

```cs
private void AddButtonToAppBar()
{
    AppBarButton buttonToAdd = new AppBarButton { Label = "Label", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Help) };
    buttonToAdd.Click += async (sender, e) =>  await new MessageDialog("Button clicked").ShowAsync();
    // add button to Page's BottoAppBar
    (BottomAppBar as CommandBar).PrimaryCommands.Add(buttonToAdd);
}
```

**Edit** - as for *Binding* (again from the top of my head, so you will have to check this) this should probably work:

```cs
Binding myBind = new Binding();
myBind.Path = new PropertyPath("GoToAddSampleItemssPageCommand");
myBind.Source = DataContext;
buttonToAdd.SetBinding(AppBarButton.CommandProperty, myBind);
```

More about [DataBinding at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Looks good. But throws a NullReferenceException at the point where it's trying to add the button. Doesn't seem to get the handle on the command bar.

Comment: @jerry It will depend when you call this method - to make this work BottomAppBar must be created before. Where do you call this method?

Comment: Ouch, even I should have figured that one out. I called it before initializing the page. It works perfectly now. Tiny detail: how about the "Command" binding?

Comment: @jerry I've added an edit but you will have to check it - I haven't got time to test it.

Comment: Thank you, Romasz. You have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around on the Windows Phone dev center, I found this page: [How to change app bar icon buttons and menu items dynamically for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394044(v=vs.105).aspx). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I think this applies to Silverlight apps though.